# Replace word in sentence based on object made of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an *ingredients* object fetched from the `API`. I want to replace *units* in each of the *ingredients* with its abbreviation. I'm trying to do it with the object called `units` and using values to be replaced in arrays, but I'm not even close to make it works.

I've tried it with many different approaches, this is my latest attempt:

```
parseIngredient() {
    const ingredients = [
      "1 fresh ham, about 18 pounds, prepared by your butcher (See Step 1)",
      "7 cloves garlic, minced",
      "1 tablespoon caraway seeds, crushed",
      "4 teaspoons salt",
      "Freshly ground pepper to taste",
      "1 teaspoon olive oil",
      "1 medium onion, peeled and chopped",
      "3 cups sourdough rye bread, cut into 1/2-inch cubes",
      "1 1/4 cups coarsely chopped pitted prunes",
      "1 1/4 cups coarsely chopped dried apricots",
      "1 large tart apple, peeled, cored and cut into 1/2-inch cubes",
      "2 teaspoons chopped fresh rosemary",
      "1 egg, lightly beaten",
      "1 cup chicken broth, homemade or low-sodium canned"
    ];

    const units = {
      tbsp: ['tablespoons', 'tablespoon', 'tbsps', 'tbsp'],
      tsp: ['teaspoons', 'teaspoon', 'tsps', 'tsp'],
      cup: ['cups', 'cup'],
      oz: ['ounces', 'ounce'],
      pt: ['pints', 'pint', 'pt'],
      gal: ['gallons', 'gallon', 'gals', 'gal'],
      pound: ['pounds', 'pound', 'lbs', 'lb'],
      qt: ['quarts', 'quart', 'qts', 'qt'],
      l: ['liters', 'liter', 'l'],
      ml: ['mililiters', 'mililiter', 'mls', 'ml'],
      cl: ['centiliters', 'centiliter', 'cls', 'cl'],
      kg: ['kilograms', 'kilogram', 'kgs', 'kg'],
      g: ['grams', 'gram', 'gs', 'g'],
      mg: ['miligrams', 'miligram', 'mgs', 'mg'],
      inch: ['inches', 'inch', 'in']
    };

    const changedIngredients = ingredients.map(el => {
        let ing = el.toLowerCase();
        const keys = Object.keys(units);
        const values = Object.values(units);

        values.forEach((value, i) => {
            for (let j; j <= value.length; j++) {
                ing = ing.replace(value[j], keys[i]);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I expect the output of `"4 teaspoons salt"` to be `"4 tbsp salt"` for example.

Comment: Seems like this would be easier if your mapping when word => abbreviation. Then you could just lookup each word in the dictionary and replace it if found.

Comment: You are not returning anything from the function that you pass to `ingredients.map`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintaining your data structure, you could first generate an array of pairs from the `units` object where each pair consist of the replacement and the regular expression used for that replacement. For generate this array of pairs we can use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) on the `units` object in conjunction with [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Note the **case insensitive** feature is added to the regular expression with the flag `i`. Also when creating the regular expression we uses [word boundaries (\b)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to match entire words and not parts of others words (like `in` inside `minced` for example). A summary of this can be seen on next logic:

```
const replacements = Object.entries(units).map(([k, v]) =>
{
    v = v.map(s => `\\b${s}\\b`).join("|");
    return [k, new RegExp(v, "i")];
});
```

Finally you can `.map()` the *ingredients*, as you already was doing, applying the respective replacements to each element of the array.

```
const changedIngredients = ingredients.map(el =>
{
    replacements.forEach(([unit, regexp]) => el = el.replace(regexp, unit));        
    return el;
});
```

## Complete Example:

```js
const ingredients = [
  "1 fresh ham, about 18 pounds, prepared by your butcher (See Step 1)",
  "7 cloves garlic, minced",
  "1 tablespoon caraway seeds, crushed",
  "4 teaspoons salt",
  "Freshly ground pepper to taste",
  "1 teaspoon olive oil",
  "1 medium onion, peeled and chopped",
  "3 cups sourdough rye bread, cut into 1/2-inch cubes",
  "1 1/4 cups coarsely chopped pitted prunes",
  "1 1/4 cups coarsely chopped dried apricots",
  "1 large tart apple, peeled, cored and cut into 1/2-inch cubes",
  "2 teaspoons chopped fresh rosemary",
  "1 egg, lightly beaten",
  "1 cup chicken broth, homemade or low-sodium canned"
];

const units = {
  tbsp: ['tablespoons', 'tablespoon', 'tbsps', 'tbsp'],
  tsp: ['teaspoons', 'teaspoon', 'tsps', 'tsp'],
  cup: ['cups', 'cup'],
  oz: ['ounces', 'ounce'],
  pt: ['pints', 'pint', 'pt'],
  gal: ['gallons', 'gallon', 'gals', 'gal'],
  pound: ['pounds', 'pound', 'lbs', 'lb'],
  qt: ['quarts', 'quart', 'qts', 'qt'],
  l: ['liters', 'liter', 'l'],
  ml: ['mililiters', 'mililiter', 'mls', 'ml'],
  cl: ['centiliters', 'centiliter', 'cls', 'cl'],
  kg: ['kilograms', 'kilogram', 'kgs', 'kg'],
  g: ['grams', 'gram', 'gs', 'g'],
  mg: ['miligrams', 'miligram', 'mgs', 'mg'],
  inch: ['inches', 'inch', 'in']
};

const replacements = Object.entries(units).map(([k, v]) =>
{
    v = v.map(s => `\\b${s}\\b`).join("|");
    return [k, new RegExp(v, "i")];
});

const changedIngredients = ingredients.map(el =>
{
    replacements.forEach(([unit, regexp]) => el = el.replace(regexp, unit));        
    return el;
});

console.log(changedIngredients);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for the desired output

```
// Polyfill of Contains method On String
if(!('contains' in String.prototype)) {
       String.prototype.contains = function(str, startIndex) {
                return -1 !== String.prototype.indexOf.call(this, str, startIndex);
       };
 }

function parseIngredient() {
  const ingredients = [
  "1 fresh ham, about 18 pounds, prepared by your butcher (See Step1)",
  "7 cloves garlic, minced",
  "1 tablespoon caraway seeds, crushed",
  "4 teaspoons salt",
  "Freshly ground pepper to taste",
  "1 teaspoon olive oil",
  "1 medium onion, peeled and chopped",
  "3 cups sourdough rye bread, cut into 1/2-inch cubes",
  "1 1/4 cups coarsely chopped pitted prunes",
  "1 1/4 cups coarsely chopped dried apricots",
  "1 large tart apple, peeled, cored and cut into 1/2-inch cubes",
  "2 teaspoons chopped fresh rosemary",
  "1 egg, lightly beaten",
  "1 cup chicken broth, homemade or low-sodium canned"
]
const units = {
  tbsp: ['tablespoons', 'tablespoon', 'tbsps', 'tbsp'],
  tsp: ['teaspoons', 'teaspoon', 'tsps', 'tsp'],
  cup: ['cups', 'cup'],
  oz: ['ounces', 'ounce'],
  pt: ['pints', 'pint', 'pt'],
  gal: ['gallons', 'gallon', 'gals', 'gal'],
  pound: ['pounds', 'pound', 'lbs', 'lb'],
  qt: ['quarts', 'quart', 'qts', 'qt'],
  l: ['liters', 'liter', 'l'],
  ml: ['mililiters', 'mililiter', 'mls', 'ml'],
  cl: ['centiliters', 'centiliter', 'cls', 'cl'],
  kg: ['kilograms', 'kilogram', 'kgs', 'kg'],
  g: ['grams', 'gram', 'gs', 'g'],
  mg: ['miligrams', 'miligram', 'mgs', 'mg'],
  inch: ['inches', 'inch', 'in']
};
const changedIngredients = ingredients.map(el => {
  let ing = el.toLowerCase();
  let shortHandedOutput=[];
  for(var prop in units){
     units[prop].map(u => {
      if(ing.contains(u)){ // Finds if the entry is in units
        ing = ing.replace(u,prop);
      }
   })
  }
  return ing;
});
}
// Execute Function
parseIngredient();
```